On zeros of real polynomials in two variables
Let $P(x,y)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients in two real variables $x,y$ such that the set of zeros of $P(x,y)$ is the real conic curve $Q(x,y)=0$. Will it be true that there exists a polynomial $R(x,y)$ such that $P(x,y)=Q(x,y)R(x,y)$? How can this be proven?"

I am not sure if your question is formulated in a precise manner, but it seems what you want is a basic application of Bezout's theorem.

What about $P(x,y)=x-y$ and $Q(x,y)=(x-y)^2$?

What if we assume that the conic $Q(x,y)$ is irreducible?

Set of zeros in what? In $\mathbf{R}^2$, the set of zero of many unrelated polynomials is empty.

I am referring to the class of polynomials with real coefficients defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that cancel out on an irreducible conic in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Now, in Hilbert's Nullstellensatz   it is assumed that the field $\mathbb{K}$ is algebraically closed. How is this reconciled with the fact that in the question the polynomial $P(x,y)$ has real coefficients and the variables $x, y$ are also real?

If $Q(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$, then $Q$ is irreducible and defines a conic, that has no real point. Then, $P(x,y)=x^4+y^2+6$ is a polynomial that is zero on the real points of the conic but is not a multiple of $P$.

@JérémyBlanc : Please see the comment by YCor.

@IosifPinelis: yes, I had seen it before writing my comment. I completely agree with him. My comment gives a negative answer to the question asked here. It is certainly not what the person asking had in mind, so it shows that the question needs to be clarified.

If all zeros of $Q$ in $\mathbb C^2$ are zeros of $P$, then, by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $Q$ divides $P^r$ for some natural $r$.
If $Q$ is also irreducible, then it follows that $Q$ divides $P$.
If $Q$ is not irreducible, then $Q$ does not have to divide $P$, as noted in my comment.

Now, how to answer the original question, for real (rather than complex) zeros -- assuming $Q$ is irreducible and the set of real zeros of $Q$ is of cardinality $>1$?
Using an affine transformation, without loss of generality $Q(x,y)$ is $x^2+y^2-1$ or $x^2-y^2-1$ or $y-x^2$.
If $Q(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$, then $p_1(t):=P(\cos t,\sin t)=0$ for all real $t$ and hence for all complex $t$, since $p_1$ is an entire function. So, in this case, all complex zeros of $Q$ are zeros of $P$.
If $Q(x,y)=x^2-y^2-1$, then $p_2(t):=P(\cosh t,\sinh t)=0$ for all real $t$ and hence for all complex $t$, since $p_2$ is an entire function. So, all complex zeros of $Q$ are zeros of $P$ in this case as well.
If finally $Q(x,y)=y-x^2$, then $p_3(t):=P(t,t^2)=0$ for all real $t$ and hence for all complex $t$, since $p_3$ is an entire function. So, all complex zeros of $Q$ are zeros of $P$ in this latter case as well.
So, it remains to use the first two sentences of this proof.

A more general result is now available.

In my question I assume that the conic $Q(x,y)$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is real and irreducible. Now, what if the zeros of $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ coincide in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not in $\mathbb{C}^2$ as stated to apply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz? So is there a counterexample to my question?

@user526214 : I have addressed this concern.

@user526214 : Do you have a further response?
